# vue - $emit vs. reference for updating parent data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We need to use `$emit` to update the parent data in a vue component. This is what has been said everywhere, even vue documentation.

`v-model` and `.sync` both use `$emit` to update, so we count them `$emit` here

what I'm involved with is updating the parent data using `reference` type passing

If we send an object or array as prop to the child component and change it in the child component, changes will be made to the parent data directly.

There are components that we always use in a specific component and we are not going to use them anywhere else. In fact, these components are mostly used to make the app codes more readable and to lighten the components of the app.

passing reference type values as prop to children for directly change them from children is much easier than passing values then handle emitted event. especially when there are more nested components

code readability is even easier when we use reference type to update parent.

For example, suppose we have `grand-parent`, `parent` and `child` components. in `parent` component we have a field that change `first` property of  grand-parent data and in child component we have another field that change `second` property of grand-parent data

If we want to implement this using `$emit` we have something like this : (we are not using .sync or v-model)

```js
// grand-parent

<template>
    <div>
        <parent :fields="fields" @updateFields="fields = $event" >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import parent from "./parent"
export default {
    components : {parent},
    data(){
        return {
            fields : {
                first : 'first-value',
                second : 'second-value',
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>




// parent

<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="fields.first" @input="updateFirstField" />
        <child :fields="fields" @updateSecondField="updateSecondField" >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "./child"
export default {
    components : {child},
    props : {
        fields : Object,
    },
    methods : {
        updateFirstField(event){
            this.$emit('updateFields' , {...this.fields , first : event.target.value})
        },
        updateSecondField(value){
            this.$emit('updateFields' , {...this.fields , second : value})
        }
    }
}
</script>




// child

<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="fields.first" @input="updateSecondField" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : {
        fields : Object,
    },
    methods : {
        updateFirstField(event){
            this.$emit('updateSecondField' , event.target.value)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Yes, we can use `.sync` to make it easier or pass just field that we need to child. but this is basic example and if we have more fields and also we use all fields in all component this is the way we do this.

same thing using reference type will be like this :

```js
// grand-parent

<template>
    <div>
        <parent :fields="fields" >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import parent from "./parent"
export default {
    components : {parent},
    data(){
        return {
            fields : {
                first : 'first-value',
                second : 'second-value',
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>




// parent

<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="fields.first" />
        <child :fields="fields" >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "./child"
export default {
    components : {child},
    props : {
        fields : Object,
    }
}
</script>




// child

<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="fields.second" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : {
        fields : Object,
    }
}
</script>
```

as you see using `reference` type is much easier. even if there was more fields.

now my question :

- should we use reference type for updating parent data or this is bad approach ?
- even if we use a component always in the same parent again we should not use this method ?
- what is the reason that we should not use `reference` type to update parent?
- if we should not use `reference` type why vue pass same object to children and not clone them before passing ? (maybe for better performance ?)

Answer (score 3):

The "always use `$emit`" rule isn't set in stone. There are pros and cons of either approach; you should do whatever makes your code easy to maintain and reason about.

For the situation you described, I think you have justified mutating the data directly.

When you have a single object with lots of properties and each property can be modified by a child component, then having the child component mutate each property itself is fine.

What would the alternative be? Emitting an event for each property update? Or emitting a single `input` event containing a copy of the object with a single property changed? That approach would result in lots of memory allocations (think of typing in a text field emitting a cloned object for each keypress). Having said that, though, some libraries are designed for this exact purpose and work pretty well (like [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/)).

For simple components that manage only small data like a textbox with a single string value, you should definitely use `$emit`. For more complex components with lots of data then sometimes it makes sense for the child component to share or own the data it is given. It becomes a part of the child component's contract that it will mutate the data in certain circumstances and in some particular way.

> what is the reason that we should not use reference type to update parent?

- The parent "owns" the data and it knows that nobody but itself will mutate it. No surprises.
- The parent gets to decide whether or not to accept the mutation, and can even modify it on-the-fly.
- You don't need a watcher to know when the data is changed.
- The parent knows *how* the data is changed and what caused the change. Imagine there are multiple ways that the data can be mutated. The parent can easily know which mutation originated from a child component. If external code (i.e. inside a child component) can mutate the data at any time and for any reason, then it becomes much more difficult for the parent to know what caused the data to change (who changed it and why?).

> if we should not use reference type why vue pass same object to children and not clone them before passing ? (maybe for better performance ?)

Well yes, for performance, but also many other reasons such as:

- Cloning is non-trivial (Shallow? Deep? Should the prototype be copied too? Does it even make sense to clone the object? Is it a singleton?).
- Cloning is expensive memory- and CPU-wise.
- If it were cloned then doing what you describe here would be impossible. It would be silly to impose such a restrictive rule.

Answer (score 0):

@Vue Detailed usage of $refs, $emit, $on:

1. $refs - parent component calls the methods of the child component. You can pass data.
2. $emit - child components call methods of the parent component and pass data.
3. $on - sibling components pass data to each other.